# Why the progress bar doesnt init on loading but after looping?

Tags: javascript, progress-bar, carousel, swiper.js

Hello guys i'm new to swiper, i try to get the progress bar working but it only work after looping for some reasons i dont understand. Maybe its a problem on init or something. Here's the code:

```
    const dataDelay = 4000;
    let speed = 1400;

    document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--delay-swiperLauncher', dataDelay + 'ms');
    document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--speed-swiperLauncher', speed + 'ms');

    // Block Carousel - Carousel
    var quoteSwiper = new Swiper('.swiper--text', {
        direction: 'horizontal',
        spaceBetween: 40,
        centerSlides: true,
        allowTouchMove: false,
        loop: true,
        autoHeight:true,
        breakpoints: {
            850: {
                direction: 'vertical',
            }
        }
    });


    var imageSwiper = new Swiper('.swiper--img', {
        allowTouchMove: false,
        loop: true,
        speed: speed,
        spaceBetween: 40,
        centerSlides: true,
        autoplay: {
            delay: dataDelay,   
            disableOnInteraction: false,    
        },
        navigation: {
            nextEl: '.swiper__arrow.swiper__arrow--next',
            prevEl: '.swiper__arrow.swiper__arrow--prev',
        },
        breakpoints: {
            850: {
                spaceBetween: 0,
                centerSlides: false,
            }
        }
    });

    imageSwiper.controller.control = quoteSwiper;
```

```
.block--carousel {
    
    .swiper--img {

        .swiper-slide {

            &::before {
                content: "";
                position: absolute;
                left: 0;
                bottom: 0;
                width: 100%;
                height: 5px;
                background: #fee7e3;

            }

            &::after {
                content: "";
                position: absolute;
                left: 0;
                bottom: 0;
                width: 0;
                height: 5px;
                border-top-right-radius: 2.5px;
                border-bottom-right-radius: 2.5px;
                background: #f72717;

                animation: animateBg;
                animation-play-state: running;

                animation-duration: calc(var(--delay-swiperLauncher) - var(--speed-swiperLauncher) * 0.5);
                animation-timing-function: linear;
                animation-fill-mode: forwards;
            }
        }


        &--is-paused {

            .swiper-slide {

                &::after {
                    animation-play-state: paused;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@keyframes animateBg {
    0% {
        width: 0;
    }

    100% {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Thank you for your time !!!!!!!!!!!
Thank you for your time !!!!!!!!!!!
Thank you for your time !!!!!!!!!!!
Thank you for your time !!!!!!!!!!!
Thank you for your time !!!!!!!!!!!
Thank you for your time !!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).